# How to add a drawable resourse in jetpack compose in Icon()

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I cannot add the R.drawable.image.png directrly to Icon()

still no answer Maybe someone can help.
As a result i might need to add i begger librarry for 200 mb - by i  do not want to do it)

I want it to llok like this
Icon(
Icon(image=  R.drawable.my_final_icon, contentDescription = null)
)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_final_icon), contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**